# Unicode GPS Coordinates to Decimal Conversion

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, gps

**The Problem**

I am using a code in python-2.7 and I have the resultant latlon expressions in an unhelpful unicode format (copied from debugger)

```
'latitude' = {unicode} u'N40°34\\'58.96"'
'longitude' = {unicode} u'W074°44\\'30.45"'
```

I want these as floats i.e.

```
'latitude' = {float} 40.583044
'longitude' = {float} -74.741792
```

**What I've Tried**

I've converted the unicodes to strings such as:

```
s = latitude.encode('utf-8')
t = longitude.encode('utf-8')
s = {str} 'N40°34\\'58.96"'
t = {str} 'W074°44\\'30.45"'
```

Problem now is that I need to remove all the unwanted characters before then converting to the correct decimal expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import re
def parseLonLat(l):
    l = re.split('[^\d\w\.]+', l)[:-1] # split into a list degree, minute, and second
    direction = l[0][0] # direction North, East, South or West
    l[0] = l[0][1:] # remove the character N or E or S or W
    return (1 if direction in ('N', 'E') else -1) * sum([float(n) / 60 ** i for i, n in enumerate(l)])
```